# Alternative to role="presentation" for HTML4 emails

Tags: html, html-email, wai-aria, screen-readers, html4

In the HTML5 doctype, you can add the `role="presentation"` attribute to an email (or any HTML5 doc using tables) and the screen reader (VoiceOver on Mac specifically) will not announce unnecessary table layout data - such as how many rows or subsequent tables are within that table.

For the HTML4 doctype, you cannot use `role="presentation"`.

Is there an alternative to adding this attribute in HTML4 that will keep the screen readers from announcing the unnecessary stuff?

Comment: Why do you want to use an HTML4 doctype? You know browsers don’t do anything with version info in the doctype, right? They don’t change their behavior depending on an HTML4 doctype vs <!doctype html>. Also as far as validation, the current W3C HTML checker https://validator.w3.org/nu/ doesn’t change any behavior depending on the doctype—it ignores the doctype & checks your document against the rules in whatever the current HTML spec is. (It’s true the legacy W3C markup validator https://validator.w3.org/ still switches behavior based on doctype, but that will changed eventually too.)

Comment: Agree with @sideshowbarker, but also `role=presentation` and all other ARIA attributes still work regardless of DOCTYPE, only difference is that checkers will complain about their use.